# Nginx won't run after import SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, web-server, ssl-certificate

I have a problem, after import commercial certificate with private key into my bitdefender gravityzone console, it stopped working. I have such errors:

```
serv bdadmin # service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
serv bdadmin # systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-03-17 16:41:48 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 26814 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 17 16:41:48 serv systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv nginx[26814]: nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /etc/nginx/conf.d/hydra-incidents-ssl.conf:7
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv nginx[26814]: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/opt/bitdefender/certs/hydra.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 17 16:41:48 serv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is any way to have back web console working even on old self-signed certificate? Anyone could help me?

Comment: Your problem is not self-signed certificate. Please read your posted log to figure out problem. It's there.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not so good at linux, do you mind I have edit something in this file? /etc/nginx/conf.d/hydra-incidents-ssl.conf

Comment: If I edit this file /etc/nginx/conf.d/hydra-incidents-ssl.conf and change 

`listen 8443;` to `listen 8444 ssl;` and comment section `#ssl on;` I have still this error, when nginx is starting: 
`Mar 17 16:41:48 serv nginx[26814]: nginx: [emerg]SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/opt/bitdefender/certs/hydra.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)`

Answer (score 2):

Your installed certificate and private key files do not match. Make sure you use the same source for both files.

Comment: yes now I see this `-rw-r--r--  1 bitdefender bitdefender 2129 Mar  9 15:58 hydra.crt
                               -rw-r--r--  1 bitdefender bitdefender 1679 Oct 13 08:18 hydra.key` I uploaded both certs on ninth march, it looks like hydra.key did not upload, check at modified date. The problem is that I cannot login as bitdefender user and only this user have privileges to change these files.